# how to close/restart phpstorm from command line

Tags: 14.04, command-line

The phpstorm is not responding and i want to kill the process.
this is the location of instalation: `/opt/phpstorm/PhpStorm-143.1770/bin`.

i cannot close it with the X button so please help me to close / restart it with the command line.

thanks.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

All "processess" that are active can be seen with the "ps" command. From command line you can type ...

```
ps -ef | grep phpstorm
```

it will list all the process IDs

```
$ ps -ef| grep phpstorm
rinzwind  2819  2812  0 11:28 ?        00:00:00 phpstorm
rinzwind  2849  2820  0 11:29 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=phpstorm
```

The line with the "grep" is what you search for. The other one the executable. A simple ...

```
kill -9 2819
```

will stop "phpstorm".

---

A shorter method:

```
pgrep -f phpstorm
```

will list just the process ID and ...

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -f phpstorm)
```

will kill it.

Programs like "top" and "htop" can be used to list running processes.

Comment: Fine fine Ill edit that in :=D My idea was to explain what "ps" does ;-)

Comment: kill: failed to parse argument: '11197
11250
11289'

Comment: sorry I cant test it on an actual phpstorm :P Is that from the last command. Cuz a "kill -9 11197 11250 11289" should work if those processes exist ;)

Comment: But `kill -9 'pid1 pid2'` won't!  A comment from [nicolas-bonnici](https://askubuntu.com/users/808411/): "You need to remove the quotes in order to make it work: `kill -9 $(pgrep -f phpstorm)`"

Comment: `kill -9 $(pgrep -f phpstorm)` worked for me... Thanks.

Comment: Just like `pgrep` there's `pkill` too. So you can just do `pkill -f phpstorm`